# QGIS: Plugin, that can import a textfile, to open a QGIS-project

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, layers

Is there a plugin for QGIS that is able to do the following steps??

QGIS imports an external text-file, opens the project and zooms to the (only) polygon that contains „xyz“ in „field1“.

the external file contains the following information:
name of the qgis-project
name of the layer (e.g. polygon-layer) – for example layer1
name of a field in this layer – for example „field1“
content of this field - for example „xyz“

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a plugin that does this (it's a fairly specific workflow), but it can certainly be achieved with a simple Python script, run from the Python console.

Firstly create your text file and save it somewhere. It should have the following structure.

*It should go without saying that this is just an example. All lines in the txt file must exactly match your own project, layer, field names etc. or you will get errors!

[image]

Next, click this icon: [image] or hit ctrl+alt+P to open the console. Open a new editor with this icon: [image]

Paste in the following script. **Note** you will need to change **two** file paths in the script, the first is the path to your txt file, the second is the path to the folder containing your project. These are indicated by comments in the script below:

```py
import os

path = 'C:\\Path\\To\\Text_File.txt'#Change to a valid path on your system
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

#print(lines)
pname = lines[0]
lname = lines[1]
fname = lines[2]
fvalue = lines[3]

def open_project_and_zoom_to_layer_feature(project_name, layer_name, field_name, field_value):
    project_folder = 'C:\\Path\\To\\Project\\Folder'# Change to match your file structure
    project_path = os.path.join(project_folder, '{}.qgs'.format(project_name))
    if not os.path.exists(project_path):
        return 0
        
    project = QgsProject.instance()
    project.read(project_path)
    
    vlayer = project.mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
    for f in vlayer.getFeatures():
        if str(f[field_name]) == str(field_value):
            iface.mapCanvas().zoomToFeatureExtent(f.geometry().boundingBox())
    return 1

result = open_project_and_zoom_to_layer_feature(pname, lname, fname, fvalue)
if result:
    print('Success!')
```

Finally, click the Run icon to run the script:

[image]

By the way, this could be made into a minimal plugin quite easily.

Comment: now a few month later I tried your python-script: I adapted the paths for my linux-computer. And made the text-file.txt with 4 lines (project-name, layer-name, feature-name, feature-value). When I start the script the result is, that the correct project opens but the script does not recognize the correct point-layer and does not zoom to the correct object. What is wrong?

Comment: now I remarked, that it works, when the target layer is a polygon layer.